# How to fix toilet spacing doesn't meet minimum 15"?

Tags: plumbing

Basement bathroom - for my quilting studio and guest suite. this will not be used regularly all year round.

I had to put a 1' filler along the wall for the linen cabinet to get the door fully open, and 1/2" filler strip between the linen cabinet and vanity for the drawers to clear, and that makes the toilet spacing from vanity to drain center about 13 1/2"; code minimum is 15". The other side of the toilet has 20.5" spacing to the tub. So the total space for the toilet is 34"- just not centered in that area. It looks like I could use an offset toilet flange, but the flange has already been installed, and it is not an offset. the toilet is narrow - the tank lid is 18" wide, so there is plenty of room for it.

Questions:

1. Should I talk with the inspector and see if he will pass it as is? the risk is that he won't and I need to figure out a fix.
2. Should I proceed with finishing and hope the inspector will just glance and say okay?
3. The toilet flange is already installed, and I understand to change that to an offset flange to gain the 1 1/2" spacing to meet code, will need to jack hammer out the existing flange or replace the custom vanity/linen cabinet which has been its own little fiasco.
4. Someone suggested putting in a smaller cheap vanity just for the inspection, then change it out to the custom one. Kind of cheating, but I am just not sure what to do !

Answer (score 1):

It reads like you have already answered your own question: either get rid of the vanity or move the toilet flange over, if you need to abide by a toilet side clearance code.

Google "offset toilet flange" for hundreds of hits, including Amazon and the big box stores.

It may be easier and better drainage to just place a new (straight) flange where you want it. A jack hammer would be overkill. A 1/2" hammer-drill will do on the concrete basement floor.

Comment: considering that the vanity cost well over $600, and matches all the rest of the cabinetry, replacing that is at the bottom of the list of solutions. what I really want is an offset toilet flange extender that fits on top of the existing flange- but I cant locate one - not sure if they make them.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than breakout the concrete floor, I’d use an “offset” and build a platform a few inches above the existing concrete slab.

Try one of these offsets: [https://www.amazon.com/Sioux-Chief-Manufacturing-889-GPOM-SIOUX/dp/B079GPGDDJ/ref=asc_df_B079GPGDDJ/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=309763036017&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17674289183164903364&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9033075&hvtargid=aud-799728744414:pla-568862517960&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079GPGDDJ)